# How to override previous array value

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function (method?)

```
clearSquares()
```

that resets this array:

```
string squares[25] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"," 15","16","17","18","19"," 20","21","22","23","24"," 25"};
```

after it is altered, back to its original values when called

```
void clearSquares()
{
    string squares[25] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"," 15","16","17","18","19"," 20","21","22","23","24"," 25"};
}
```

but when it is called, the values remain the same. How do I resolve this? Or is there another more elegant way to reset the original array values?

ps: the numbers are strings on purpouse

Comment: `squares` is a local variable in your function, which shadows the global one, hence you'll never see any changes to the global variable. You can use `std::copy()` to solve that.

Comment: Please [edit] ans show a [mcve]. It's easier to understand than a description of what your code does (or is supposed to do).

Comment: Even though both the variables have the same name, they are, nevertheless, different. So modifying one will, obviously, not affect the other.

Comment: BTW you should create these strings dynamically. 1,2,3,4... I see a pattern there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables; one global and one local to `clearSquares`. These have nothing to do with each other.
Since you can't assign to arrays, avoiding having a local one will not help.

But you only need one function, both for initial setup and clearing.

Something like

```
void resetSquares()
{
    int i = 1;
    for (auto& x: squares)
    {
        x = std::to_string(i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Normal loop would be fine here, kind of reusing the `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenters has pointed out, you are creating a local variable and modifying that.

You probably want to do something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3x9hqYahx)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> createSquares() {
   std::vector<std::string> s;
   for (size_t i = 1; i <= 25; ++i) {
      s.push_back(std::to_string(i));
   }
   return s;
}

auto squares = createSquares();

int main() {
    // And when clearing do the same thing:
    squares = createSquares();
}
```